# Send custom data for Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I am using GA event tracking to track usage on my app. I want to send data together with the events. Currently, this is the way I am using event tracking:

```
func trackEvent(data: NSDictionary? = nil){
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set(kGAIUserId, value: UserService.getUserId())
    let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data!, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    let stringJson = String(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEventWithCategory("book", action: "view", label: stringJson, value: nil)
    tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject:AnyObject])
}
```

JsonData was stringtified and embeded in event Label which obviously is not really nice. So I wonder there is another way that I can embed data in an event. I saw an example from Google to send event's fieldsObject with javascript: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

But I cannot find any equivalent way to do it on iOS yet. Hope that someone can share me some knowledge on this. Thanks